# Xamarin ListView with auto fit row height

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I need to co create listView that set row height depends of its content. Another problem is when is set `HasUnevenRows="true"` then it makes a lot of empty space under my components in listView.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true">
...
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use BindableLayout

```
<StackLayout
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Item}" Padding="30,10">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label
                    Text="{Binding .}"
                    TextColor="Black" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Item { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Item.Add($"Abc{i}");
        }
    }
```